Manually setting up GParted on USB - unclear instruction regarding makeboot.bat
I'm using Windows Method B: Manual from GParted website
After copying all files from ISO archive to the USB it says the following

Browse to your USB flash drive and as an administrator (On the USB flash key, create a shortcut to the makeboot.bat file. Then right-clic
on the shortcut, Properties, Advanced and check "Run as
administrator".), click the makeboot.bat in the dir utils\win32.
WARNING! Makeboot.bat must be run from your USB flash drive.

First of all there are two makefile.bat files for Windows (Win32 and Win64)

I assume I'm supposed to use the makeboot64.bat file if on a 64 bit system?

Secondly

Where am I supposed to create the shortcut and why is this necessary?
It then says to click the makeboot.bat file from folder utils\win32\ but then what was the point of creating the shortcut to it if we are clicking it directly?

Confused here.  Does anyone know the correct procedure here?
